# Code formatting following numbered list breaks

Tags: support, formatting

Something was breaking in [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/9523/2118). A code-formatted block follows a numbered list, and the code isn't `<pre>`-formatted. I'm guessing that it has to do with the many `<` and `>` symbols involved. Workaround is to put a dummy tag between the list and code block.

## example text:

```
A ***CORDIC division*** is implemented using ***CORDIC multiplication***, rearranging as follows:

    c = a/b
    a - c*b = 0

For the multiplication `z = x*y`:

> <sup>[[source]][2]</sup> ***z*** is composed of shifted versions of ***y***. The unknown value for ***z***, may be found by driving ***x*** to zero 1 bit at a time. If the *i<sup><sup> </sup>th</sup>* bit of ***x*** is nonzero, ***y**<sup><sup> </sup>i</sup>* is right shifted by *i* bits and added to the current value of ***z***. The *i<sup><sup> </sup>th</sup>* bit is then removed from ***x*** by subtracting *2<sup>-i</sup>* from ***x***. If ***x*** is negative, the *i<sup><sup> </sup>th</sup>* bit in the twos complement format would be removed by adding *2<sup>-i</sup>*. In either case, when ***x*** has been driven to zero all bits have been examined and ***z*** contains the signed product of ***x*** and ***y*** correct to *B* bits.

>This algorithm is similar to the standard shift and add multiplication algorithm except for two important features:

> 1. Arithmetic right shifts  are used instead of left shifts, allowing signed numbers to be used.
> 2. Computing the product to *B* bits with the CORDIC algorithm is equivalent to rounding the result of the standard algorithm to the most significant *B* bits.


>     divide_4q(x,y){
>        for (i=1; i=<B; i++){
>           if (x > 0)
>             if (y > 0)
>                x = x - y*2^(-i);
>                z = z + 2^(-i);
>             else
>                x = x + y*2^(-i);
>                z = z - 2^(-i);
>           else          
>              if (y > 0)
>                 x = x + y*2^(-i);
>                 z = z - 2^(-i);
>              else
>                 x = x - y*2^(-i);
>                 z = z + 2^(-i);
>        }
>        return(z)
>     }
```

## Broken result:

> A ***CORDIC division*** is implemented
>   using ***CORDIC multiplication***,
>   rearranging as follows:
>
> ```
> c = a/b
> a - c*b = 0
> ```
>
> For the multiplication `z = x*y`:
>
> > <sup>[[source]](http://www.drdobbs.com/184404244)</sup> ***z*** is composed of shifted versions of
> >     ***y***. The unknown value for ***z***, may be found by driving ***x*** to zero 1 bit at a time. If the *i <sup>th</sup>* bit
> >     of ***x*** is nonzero,
> >     ***y*** <sup>i</sup> is right shifted by *i* bits and added to
> >     the current value of ***z***. The
> >     *i <sup>th</sup>* bit is then removed from ***x*** by
> >     subtracting *2<sup>-i</sup>* from
> >     ***x***. If ***x*** is negative, the *i <sup>th</sup>* bit in the twos complement format would be
> >     removed by adding *2<sup>-i</sup>*. In
> >     either case, when ***x*** has been
> >     driven to zero all bits have been
> >     examined and ***z*** contains the
> >     signed product of ***x*** and ***y***
> >     correct to *B* bits.
> >
> > This algorithm is similar to the standard shift and add multiplication
> >     algorithm except for two important
> >     features:
> >
> > 1. Arithmetic right shifts  are used instead of left shifts, allowing
> >        signed numbers to be used.
> > 2. Computing the product to *B* bits with the CORDIC algorithm is
> >        equivalent to rounding the result of
> >        the standard algorithm to the most
> >        significant *B* bits.
> >
> >    divide_4q(x,y){
> >           for (i=1; i= 0)
> >                if (y > 0)
> >                   x = x - y*2^(-i);
> >                   z = z + 2^(-i);
> >                else
> >                   x = x + y*2^(-i);
> >                   z = z - 2^(-i);
> >              else
> >                 if (y > 0)
> >                    x = x + y*2^(-i);
> >                    z = z - 2^(-i);
> >                 else
> >                    x = x - y*2^(-i);
> >                    z = z + 2^(-i);
> >           }
> >           return(z)
> >        }

## Fixed result:

<sup>*(with `<tyblus-unbreak-tag>` between numbered list and code block)*</sup>

> A ***CORDIC division*** is implemented
>   using ***CORDIC multiplication***,
>   rearranging as follows:
>
> ```
> c = a/b
> a - c*b = 0
> ```
>
> For the multiplication `z = x*y`:
>
> > <sup>[[source]](http://www.drdobbs.com/184404244)</sup> ***z*** is composed of shifted versions of
> >     ***y***. The unknown value for ***z***, may be found by driving ***x*** to zero 1 bit at a time. If the *i <sup>th</sup>* bit
> >     of ***x*** is nonzero,
> >     ***y*** <sup>i</sup> is right shifted by *i* bits and added to
> >     the current value of ***z***. The
> >     *i <sup>th</sup>* bit is then removed from ***x*** by
> >     subtracting *2<sup>-i</sup>* from
> >     ***x***. If ***x*** is negative, the *i <sup>th</sup>* bit in the twos complement format would be
> >     removed by adding *2<sup>-i</sup>*. In
> >     either case, when ***x*** has been
> >     driven to zero all bits have been
> >     examined and ***z*** contains the
> >     signed product of ***x*** and ***y***
> >     correct to *B* bits.
> >
> > This algorithm is similar to the standard shift and add multiplication
> >     algorithm except for two important
> >     features:
> >
> > 1. Arithmetic right shifts  are used instead of left shifts, allowing
> >        signed numbers to be used.
> > 2. Computing the product to *B* bits with the CORDIC algorithm is
> >        equivalent to rounding the result of
> >        the standard algorithm to the most
> >        significant *B* bits.
>
> > ```
> > divide_4q(x,y){
> >    for (i=1; i=<B; i++){
> >       if (x > 0)
> >         if (y > 0)
> >            x = x - y*2^(-i);
> >            z = z + 2^(-i);
> >         else
> >            x = x + y*2^(-i);
> >            z = z - 2^(-i);
> >       else          
> >          if (y > 0)
> >             x = x + y*2^(-i);
> >             z = z - 2^(-i);
> >          else
> >             x = x - y*2^(-i);
> >             z = z + 2^(-i);
> >    }
> >    return(z)
> > }
> > ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/editing-help

1. You must indent code 8 spaces if you want it to be code formatted *as part of the list*.
2. If you need code formatting immediately following a list (but **not as a part of the list**) then you need to either insert a paragraph between or a no-op HTML tag like a HTML comment